# My program is not updating its output

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a kind of simple progress bar, when each half a second the percentage is going up; The output is constantly updating itself. For this I tried to use the '\r' argument, but the code just ignores it and prints the progress bar over and over until it gets to 100 percent.

Here is the code:

```
import time
def progressBar(value, endvalue, bar_length=20):
    while value <= endvalue:
        percent = float(value) / endvalue
        arrow = '-' * int(round(percent * bar_length)-1) + '>'
        spaces = ' ' * (bar_length - len(arrow))
        print("\rPercent: [{0}] {1}%".format(arrow + spaces, int(round(percent * 100))))
        value+=1
        time.sleep(0.5)

progressBar(1, 100)
```

output:

```
Percent: [>                   ] 1%

Percent: [>                   ] 2%

Percent: [>                   ] 3%

Percent: [>                   ] 4%

Percent: [>                   ] 5%

Percent: [>                   ] 6%

Percent: [>                   ] 7%

Percent: [->                  ] 8%

Percent: [->                  ] 9%

Percent: [->                  ] 10%

Percent: [->                  ] 11%
```

And so on and on.

Can someone tell me what is the problem here?

Comment: for arrow variable you are missing multiplication with 100

Comment: print() will append newline after the message to be printed.  Try `print("Percent: ...", end='\r')`.

Comment: it just prints everything as if I wrote (end=' ')

Comment: probably because of the IDE you are using, test it in a console.

Comment: tried on console, same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell `print()` *not* to print a newline:

```
print("\rPercent: [{0}] {1}%".format(arrow + spaces, int(round(percent * 100))),
      end="")
```

Setting `end` to an empty string replaces the default `\n` written.

You probably want to add a `print()` after the `while` loop is complete to add an explicit newline.

Demo with just `end=""`:

[image: GIF video of progress bar]

You may want to add `flush=True` to ensure that there isn't a buffer problem (some terminal buffers wait for a newline before flushing):

```
print("\rPercent: [{0}] {1}%".format(arrow + spaces, int(round(percent * 100))),
      end="", flush=True)
```

Alternatively, use `sys.stdout.write()` and `sys.stdout.flush()`:

```
sys.stdout.write("\rPercent: [{0}] {1}%".format(arrow + spaces, int(round(percent * 100))))
sys.stdout.flush()
```

but `print` produces the exact same calls to `sys.stdout.write()` anyway.

Comment: it gives me this: `
Percent: [>                   ] 1%
Percent: [>                   ] 2%
Percent: [>                   ] 3%
Percent: [>                   ] 4%
Percent: [>                   ] 5%
Percent: [>                   ] 6%
Percent: [>                   ] 7%
Percent: [->                  ] 8%
Percent: [->                  ] 9%
Percent: [->                  ] 10%
Percent: [->                  ] 11%
Percent: [->                  ] 12%
Percent: [-->                 ] 13%
Percent: [-->                 ] 14%
Percent: [--> `

Comment: it is ignoring my '\r' somehow

Comment: @DanielEngel: what console are you using? `\r` needs to be supported by the console or terminal. It won't work in many IDE's for example.

Comment: In terminal it doesn't even open for me

Comment: @DanielEngel: that doesn't tell me anything; I've added a demo video of the code pasted into an interactive Python 3.5 session.

Comment: when I write end="" it complains with an error: invalid syntax (only on  console)

Comment: @DanielEngel: did you include the comma after the other argument to the `print()` function? Or are you using Python 2 (where `print` is a *statement* not a function)?

Comment: @DanielEngel: if you are using Python 2, I recommend you use `from __future__ import print_function` at the top of your script. Alternatively, remove the `()` parentheses and use `print "...".format(...),` (adding a comma after the string you are printing) or use `import sys` then `sys.stdout.write("...".format(...))` to write directly to stdout without a newline.

Comment: I am using python 3

Comment: @DanielEngel: then either you didn't copy my altered `print()` function exactly, or you *also* have Python 2 installed and accidentally ran that in the terminal. Hard to tell without seeing your exact code and output.

Comment: my code is the same as yours

Comment: Yet mine doesn't have a syntax error. We are going in circles here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121042/discussion-between-daniel-engel-and-martijn-pieters).

Answer (score 0):

Existing progressbar-implementations (also in other applications, MATLAB, e.g.) go to great lengths to track the number of characters they send to the output stream at each update, so that they can send as many backspace-characters \b needed to "erase" those characters. (And it depends on your platform/console and how your script is called.)

The \r doesn't work like you'd expect in the output-stream of a console.

Comment: `\r` works just fine in *most* terminals. Not in all consoles (IDE output windows) however.

Comment: so what other way should I use that is not confusing as hell?

Comment: @MartijnPieters you are right of course (although I'm not sure if we can make a reliable quantitative statement about the ratio between terminals where it works or not). Considering the number of terminals which don't support \r as wanted, it's safer to expect that it doesn't when writing a piece of code.

And even then, running a script through batch on Windows 7 for example, can't handle "backspacing" past a multi-line progressbar correctly.

Comment: @PierreSchroeder: it's good enough for Mercurial; the [progress bar code uses `\r`](https://selenic.com/hg/file/tip/mercurial/progress.py#l161).

Answer (score 0):

I have installed python **2.7.10** in **OSX 10.11.6**, and the following code may meet your requirement in the Terminal

```
import time
import sys
def progressBar(value, endvalue, bar_length=20):
    while value <= endvalue:
        percent = float(value) / endvalue
        arrow = '-' * int(round(percent * bar_length)-1) + '>'
        spaces = ' ' * (bar_length - len(arrow))
        print("\rPercent: [{0}] {1}%".format(arrow + spaces, int(round(percent * 100))))
        sys.stdout.write("\033[F")
        value+=1
        time.sleep(0.5)

progressBar(1, 100)
```

Comment: sorry, still the same output on console